# Sending emails consistently returns 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful code or some variation of an authentication failure

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I can't for the life of me figure this out. Currently using MailKit + Godaddy email accounts (through Office365).

I don't have 2FA enabled, user/pass is correct. No matter what combination of settings I do, email doesn't work.

This is the code I'm using currently (I've also tried System.Net's SmtpClient using a ton of different setups, and nothing works)-

```
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        using var client = new SmtpClient();

        await client.ConnectAsync(Host, Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

        await client.AuthenticateAsync(User, Pass);

        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("", FromAddress));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", email));
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html) { Text = htmlMessage };

        try
        {
            await client.SendAsync(message);
            await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You likely need to tweak your account security settings before you can access them with SMTP (you certainly need to with Gmail). Alternatively, have you considered using an e-mail sending API such as Amazon's SES, SendGrid, etc?

Comment: I would consider editing this question and removing all the gunk and just leave the facts

Comment: Seconding @John. I had to configure my gmail account to allow sending emails through .net. I know it's annoying but if you were around in the 90s you may remember how rampant stuff like smtp spoofing was.

Comment: @John I'm going to try out SendGrid. I've been looking for some other manager. This might be exactly what I need.

Comment: @Ethan If you do, make sure you set up DKIM and SPF records on your source domain (SendGrid will have these documented somewhere) so that e-mails don't get incorrectly flagged as spam by the recipient's email servers.

Comment: @John I did, it's already all set up. Emails are working. Everything is working. I'm going to go for a drive now and think about how the last 5 hours of my life has been wasted and cry for a bit and then get over it and get back to working on this app. Thank you so much.